# Is there a way to prove two similar series converge to different values?

Tags: sequences-and-series

For $\alpha\in[0,1/2)$, define the functions $F(t),G(t)$ by
$$F(t): = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{{n^\alpha}\sqrt{n}} \cos(t\log{n})\qquad G(t) := \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{{n^{-\alpha}}\sqrt{n}} \cos(t\log{n}).$$

It is known that at some value $t_0$, one of the two series converges to $0$. Is there way to prove that then the other series is not equal to $0$ at $t_0$, either diverging or having any other value different from $0$ ?

Comment: what is the range of $\alpha$? If $\alpha> 1/2$ then the first series converges uniformly.

Comment: $\alpha \in [0, \frac{1}{2})$ but it is known that one or the other converges for sure.

Comment: What's known about $f(x)$? If $f(n) = (2n+1)\pi / 2$ for example, then both series converge.

Comment: f(x) alternates somehow randomly. I am not concerned about the convergence or not of the series. In any case $f(x)$ could be something like: $f(x) = t\log{n}$

Comment: Sorry the question is not clear.  We know one of the series converge, and it does it to $0$. I am interesting in assuring the other series, then it is different for $0$, convergent or not.

Comment: @abr You'll need to define "*somehow randomly*" better.

Comment: @dxiv sure, let $f(x) = t\log{n}$, where $t$ is known parameter.

Comment: @abr Well, then edit that bit of information into the question, since it is kind of essential.

Comment: also observe that $F$ cannot be a function on $n$. The same for $G$. You need to change the index of summation.

Comment: Thanks for comments divx @Masacroso I have tried to edit the question so all your comments are reflected there.

Comment: No, $F$ and $G$ are functions of $t$, not $n$.  $n$ is a dummy variable used in the summation on the right.  It seems unlikely that either one converges to $0$ for all $t$.  Do you mean that you know there is some $t$ that one converges to zero at?  One of them will clearly diverge if $|\alpha| \ge \frac 12$

Comment: @RossMillikan it is known that there is  a parameter t, for wich one of the series converges.  It is also known that $\alpha<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: if $\alpha\in[0,1/2)$ both series converge conditionally (for long enough $n$ we knows that $t\ln n$ have the same sign for any fixed $t$). However it is not clear how to show that both series converge to different values.